# How to add xmlns in the root in XML in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I am trying to add `xmlns MsgDtTm` & `MessageId`attributes in root element of XML in SQL Server 2014. I am trying this:

```
declare @TEMP table (ID nvarchar(max), Name nvarchar(max))
declare @count int =0
WHILE @count < 4 
BEGIN  
   declare @name nvarchar(20),@id nvarchar(max)
   select @name= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 7)
         ,@id= CHAR(ROUND(RAND() * 93 + 33, 0))
   insert into @TEMP values(@id,@name)
   set @count= @count +1
END  

declare @msgId nvarchaR(24)
SET @msgId='11EXP'+REPLACE(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103),'/','')+'1'
DECLARE @Xml xml
SET @Xml = (select * from @TEMP for xml path('DefaultName'), type)
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://abc.go.com')
select GETDATE() as "@MsgDtTm"
  ,@msgId as "@MessageId"
  ,--'http://abc.go.com' as "@xmlns",
@Xml for xml path('Person')
```

and getting this result

```
<Person xmlns="http://abc.go.com" MsgDtTm="2016-11-21T15:13:10.440" MessageId="11EXP211120161">
  <DefaultName xmlns="">
    <ID>y</ID>
    <Name>7BDCB6</Name>
  </DefaultName>
  <DefaultName xmlns="">
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>F8E997</Name>
  </DefaultName>
  <DefaultName xmlns="">
    <ID>"</ID>
    <Name>01E71C</Name>
  </DefaultName>
  <DefaultName xmlns="">
    <ID>k</ID>
    <Name>E4059A</Name>
  </DefaultName>
</Person>
```

I am getting the blank `xmlns` attribute in `Default` element. I want `xmlns` in `Person` element not in `Default` element. My expected result is as follows:

```
<Person xmlns="http://abc.go.com" MsgDtTm="2016-11-21T15:13:10.440" MessageId="11EXP211120161">
  <DefaultName>
    <ID>y</ID>
    <Name>7BDCB6</Name>
  </DefaultName>
  <DefaultName>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>F8E997</Name>
  </DefaultName>
  <DefaultName>
    <ID>"</ID>
    <Name>01E71C</Name>
  </DefaultName>
  <DefaultName>
    <ID>k</ID>
    <Name>E4059A</Name>
  </DefaultName>
</Person>
```

if I use `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://abc.go.com' as f)` then it will be in root but in result I will get `xmlns:f="..."`. I don't want to append `:objectOfXMLNAMESPACES`, I just want xmlns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a very annoying behaviour, that SQL Server adds namespaces to each sub-select over and over.

You will find a lot of workarounds here on SO, some use an ugly cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to insert the namespace on string base, other use more or less complicated ways.

For you the simplest should be this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://abc.go.com')
SELECT @xml=
    (
        SELECT ID,Name
        FROM @TEMP
        FOR XML PATH('DefaultName'),ROOT('Person'),TYPE
    );
DECLARE @d DATETIME=GETDATE();
DECLARE @mid VARCHAR(100)='11EXP'+REPLACE(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103),'/','')+'1';

SET @xml.modify('insert (attribute MsgDtTm {sql:variable("@d")}
                        ,attribute MessageId {sql:variable("@mid")}) into (/*:Person)[1]');

SELECT @xml;
```

### IMPORTANT

Please [follow this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements), sign in, and vote up.

This is a well known issue lasting for **years!!**..

Comment: Nice trick. As a side note, you can add multiple attributes in a single statement, thus reducing overhead: `SET @xml.modify('insert (attribute MsgDtTm {sql:variable("@d")}, attribute MessageId {sql:variable("@mid")}) into (/*:Person)[1]');`

Comment: @RogerWolf. Thx, didn't know that. I've tried it actually, but did not use wrapping paranthesis... Good to know, Happy Coding!