# TSQL xml output with namespaces

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml-namespaces

Looking for insight as how to better control where SQL Server 2016 puts XML namespaces.  Below is the query that formats the data correctly (please don't ask why the subData, I know not, wish it wasn't so, but it is... )

```
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.adomain.com' as ns2)
 select td1.id as '@id',
    (
    select td2.questionNumber, td2.questionType, td2.section
    from @TestData td2
    where td1.id = td2.id
    FOR XML PATH('subData'), TYPE
    ) as xml_output
   from @TestData td1
order by td1.questionNumber
 FOR XML path ('mainData'), ROOT('ns2:theRoot');
```

The output is spot on, but for some reason it always puts xmlns:ns2="http://www.adomain.com" on each subData.  How does the query need to change so that the namespace is only on theRoot?

```
<ns2:theRoot xmlns:ns2="http://www.adomain.com">
    <mainData id="A_SHORTA">
        <xml_output>
            <subData xmlns:ns2="http://www.adomain.com">
                <questionNumber>A_SHORTA</questionNumber>
                <questionType>rad</questionType>
                <section>A</section>
            </subData>
        </xml_output>
    </mainData>
</ns2:theRoot>
```

Comment: This is a very annoying (but still correct) behaviour you cannot change *legally*. There are tons of related examples )and I'll pick one and close this as duplicate in a minute), just [one of my own answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49653985/5089204) with useful links, how to proceed with more or less ugly hacks :-D

Comment: You can try post-processing the XML with an XSLT identity transformation, this should compress the namespaces.